# How get current month short name with jquery ui datepicker instead full month name?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

My code that give  long month name instead short name:

```
var monthShortName=$.datepicker.formatDate('MM d, yy', new Date(),{ monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','Maj','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Okt','Nov','Dec'] });

alert(monthShortNam); // "March" and not like i want "Mar"
```

Thanks

(I use JQuery 1.7.1 + jQuery UI 1.8.2)

**Edit - Eliasson Solution('M' and not 'MM'):**

```
$.datepicker.formatDate('M d, yy', new Date());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate), for short month names you use `M` not `MM` in your date format.

```
$.datepicker.formatDate('M d, yy', 
    new Date(),
   { monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','Maj','Jun','Jul',
                      'Aug','Sep','Okt','Nov','Dec'] 
});
```

Comment: $.datepicker.formatDate('M d, yy', 
    new Date()); also works great - "M" instead "MM" solve the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
var monthname=new Array("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");
            var monName = monthname[currentDate.getMonth()]; 
console.log(monName);
```

Comment: Can you add some comments to clarify your answer? It will help OP and others to understand it.